# What criterion was used to build the list of english stop words in nltk (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, stop-words

I wonder why words like "therefore" or "however" or "etc" are not included for instance.
**Can you suggest a strategy to make this list automatically more general?**
One obvious solution is to include every word that arises in all documents. However, maybe in some documents "therefore" cannot arise. 
Just to be clear I am not talking about augment the list by including words of specific data sets. For instance, in some data sets, it may be interested to filter some proper names. I am not talking about this. I am talking about the inclusion of general words that can appear in any english text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with tinkering with a stop word list is that there is no good way to gather all texts about a certain topic and then automatically *discard* everything that occurs too frequent. It may lead to inadvertently removing just the topic that you were looking for – *because* in a limited corpus it occurs relatively frequent. Also, any list of stop words may already contain just the phrase you are looking for. As an example, automatically creating a list of 1980s music groups would almost certainly discard the group [The The](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_The).

The [NLTK documentation](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) refers to where their stopword list came from as:

> Stopwords Corpus, Porter et al.

However, that reference is not very well written. It seems to state this was part of the 1980's *Porter Stemmer* (PDF: http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~marie/undervisning/textanalys16/porter.pdf; thanks go to [alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis) for the link), but this actually does not mention stop words. Another source states that:

> The Porter et al refers to the original Porter stemmer paper I believe - Porter, M.F. (1980): An algorithm for suffix stripping. Program 14 (3): 130—37. - although the et al is confusing to me. I remember being told the stopwords for English that the stemmer used came from a different source, likely this one - "Information retrieval" by C. J. Van Rijsbergen (Butterworths, London, 1979).
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nltk-users/c8GHEA8mq8A

The full text of Van Rijsbergen can be found online (PDF: http://openlib.org/home/krichel/courses/lis618/readings/rijsbergen79_infor_retriev.pdf); it mentions several approaches to preprocessing text and so may well be worth a full read. From a quick glance-through it seems the preferred algorithm to generate a stop word list goes all the way back to research such as

> LUHN, H.P., 'A statistical approach to mechanised encoding and searching of library information', IBM Journal of Research and Development, 1, 309-317 (1957).

dating back to the very early stages of automated text processing.

Comment: Unfortunately the [Porter paper](http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~marie/undervisning/textanalys16/porter.pdf) cited in the nltk-users thread does not mention a stopwords list (plus it has Porter as the sole author, hence no "et al."). I suspect the correct reference might be a later publication.

Comment: @alexis: I didn't think of checking out the original paper, thanks for that link. I find *lots* of statements like "The NLTK stopwords come from the original 1980 Porter stemmer paper by M F Porter" (https://martinapugliese.github.io/english-stopwords/) but a paper such as "[The automatic identification of stop words](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247786801_The_automatic_identification_of_stop_words)" indeed clearly separates generating a stop word list from the *word stemming* as outlined in the Porter article. One of the NLTK documentation writers jumped to conclusions.

Comment: @alexis: (ctd., sorry :) But do note that careful reading from my google groups quote indeed states about the stop word list that they "... came from a different source ..." and so only the NLTK reference itself is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The title of your question asks about the criteria that were used to compile the stopwords list. A look at `stopwords.readme()` will point you to the [Snowball source code](https://anoncvs.postgresql.org/cvsweb.cgi/pgsql/src/backend/snowball/#dirlist), and based on what I read there I believe the list was basically hand-compiled, and its primary goal was the exclusion of irregular word forms in order to provide better input to the stemmer. So if some uninteresting words were excluded, it was not a big problem for the system.

As for how you could build a better list, that's a pretty big question. You could try computing a TF-IDF score for each word in your corpus. Words that never get a high tf-idf score (for any document) are uninteresting, and can go in the stopword list.